# expressjs route not working for a simple route but console.log is working which is placed befor res.render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

forgot.js

```js
/* eslint-disable */
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('forgot');
    res.render('forgot', { title: 'Forgot Password' });
})

export default router;
```

app.js

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import Debug from 'debug';
import express from 'express';
import logger from 'morgan';
// import favicon from 'serve-favicon'
import path from 'path';
import sassMiddleware from 'node-sass-middleware';

import session from 'express-session';
import validator from 'express-validator';

import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

import index from './routes/index';
import forgot from './routes/forgot';
// import dashboard from './routes/dashboard';

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/portal';

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Database created!');
  db.close();
});

const app = express();
const debug = Debug('students-registration-portal:app');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
// view engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
// app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(validator());
app.use(session({ secret: 'jesse', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true, cookie: { maxAge: 60000 } }));
app.use(sassMiddleware({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  indentedSyntax: true,
  sourceMap: true
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/forgot', forgot);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
/* eslint no-unused-vars: 0 */
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

// Handle uncaughtException
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  debug('Caught exception: %j', err);
  process.exit(1);
});

export default app;
```

Here, index route is working, but forgot route is not working, it is redirecting me to error page.

I used yoman es6 express generator.

the console.log('forgot') statement is working but res.render(...) is not working (even if I place a return statement before it).

I have used the same logic for forgot route which I used in index route.

forgot.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  .center.center_cont
    .container.ms-u-slideRightIn40
      p.ms-font-xxl Sign In
    .container.ms-u-slideRightIn20
      form(action='/', method='POST')
        .ms-TextField.text_box
          label.ms-Label E-mail
          input.ms-TextField-field(type="email", value=email, name="email", id="email")
        button.ms-Button.ms-Button--primary(type='submit')
          span.ms-Button-label Send Email
       br
       br
       a(href='/register') create an account
```

Comment: which express version you are using ?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.16.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "debug": "^2.6.8",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "express-session": "^1.15.5",
    "express-validator": "^3.2.1",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.31",
    "monk": "^6.0.3",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^0.11.0",
    "nodemailer": "^4.1.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.2"
  }

Comment: express - 4.15.4

Comment: Do you have 'forgot' template in the views folder?

Comment: yes, if I'm replacing res.render(...) with res.send('....'), it is working, but i need to render a template

Comment: yarn start v1.0.1
$ node ./bin/start
connected to db!
......
forgot
GET /forgot 500 19.916 ms - 430
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1.568 ms - -
GET /lib/fabric.min.css 304 2.123 ms - -
GET /lib/fabric.components.min.css 304 3.415 ms - -
GET /lib/fabric.min.js 304 3.056 ms - -
GET /images/city_wp.jpg 304 0.848 ms - -

Comment: Please add the pug view template file too for 'forget' for better solution